# Eclipse development installer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My team is using Eclipse as a development env with some plugins installed on it.

I'd like to make an installer to allow all the new developers joining our team to give them the installer having in "one shot" all they need to get started with the development.

Does Eclipse provide any features like that?

This installer has to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

The [Oomph Eclipse project](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Installer) helps setting up a development environment. It was created for Eclipse committers themselves, but you can use it for your own corporate usage. It downloads the required plugins, sets up preferences, imports projects from your SCM, configures working sets, etc.
There are a number of tutorials available on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Example of installation "SWTBot testing tool", "Business Intelligence Reporting Tool" and "Model Workflow Engine" over "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" via "[console version of Oomph installer](https://github.com/a-langer/eclipse-oomph-console)":

```
./eclipse-inst -nosplash -application org.eclipse.oomph.console.application -vmargs \
  -Doomph.installation.location="$PWD/ide" \
  -Doomph.product.id="epp.package.java" \
  -Doomph.project.id="swtbot,birt,MWE" \
  -Doomph.workspace.location="$PWD/workspace" \
  -Doomph.installation.id="eclipse-with-swtbot-birt-mwe" \
  -Dsetup.p2.agent="$HOME/.p2"
```

You can specify your own list of projects in a variable `oomph.project.id`. See list of available [projects](https://projects.eclipse.org/) and setup [models](https://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/org.eclipse.projects.setup) of projects. Or create own setup model, such as [ProjectCatalog.setup](https://github.com/a-langer/eclipse-oomph-console/blob/main/org.eclipse.oomph.console.product/setups/ProjectCatalog.setup) for "Bash editor" plugin.

Comment: You seem to be providing the same information that was given in a previous answer a while ago.

Comment: Answer clarified